# How to use FIND_IN_SET if the values has commas?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I want to use the function FIND_IN_SET to "ORDER BY" mysql results from a query, the problem is that the values has COMMAS inside like this:

```
valu,e1
value,2
va,lue3
val,ue4
```

Now when I do the query I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET( column, 'valu,e1,value,2,va,lue3,val,ue4' );
```

As you can see the "," is used to separate the values, but the values has "," inside them ...

I tryed some solutions without succes like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET( column, 'valu\,e1,value\,2,va\,lue3,val\,ue4' );
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET( column, '\'valu,e1\',\'value,2\',\'va,lue3\',\'val,ue4\'' );
```

BUT, anything of that worked fine!

Do you know what is the correct solution for this??? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this function is the right answer/way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY FIELD( 
   column, 'valu,e1', 'value,2', 'va,lue3', 'val,ue4' 
);
```